# Cannot uncheck checkbox in smartgwt listgrid

Tags: gwt, checkbox, smartgwt, listgrid

I'm breaking my head since a whole day now but cannot find a solution, I hope someone can help me.

I'm trying to create a simple SmartGWT ListGrid with checkboxes and for some reason I can only check checkboxes but not uncheck them.
Once the checkbok is checked there is no way to uncheck it.
Below the code I'm using to create the grid.
Here I first instantiate the grid that is populated later with a call to the server.
Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? Anything wrong with the initialisation maybe?
Thanks in advance!!

```
[...]

ListGrid hotelsGrid = new ListGrid();

hotelsGrid.enableHiliting(false);
hotelsGrid.setCanSort(false);
hotelsGrid.setCanResizeFields(false); 
hotelsGrid.setShowHeader(false);
hotelsGrid.setAutoFitData(Autofit.BOTH);
hotelsGrid.setStyleName("selectGrid");
hotelsGrid.setCanEdit(false);
hotelsGrid.setShowHover(false);
hotelsGrid.setShowRollOver(false);
hotelsGrid.setShowSelectedStyle(false);
hotelsGrid.setSelectionAppearance(SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX);

[...]

private void initGrid(String[] sParams){

ListGridField flagField = new ListGridField("flagField", "Status", 40);
flagField.setAlign(Alignment.CENTER);
flagField.setType(ListGridFieldType.IMAGE);
flagField.setImageURLPrefix("flags/");
flagField.setImageURLSuffix(".png");

ListGridField textField = new ListGridField("textField", "Meaning");

hotelsGrid.setFields(flagField, textField);
hotelsGrid.setData(getSelectRecords(sParams));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear how your code sample above is related to a clickable checkbox - your code doesn't make any attempt to create a field with checkboxes??

All you need to do to get a clickable checkbox is declare a field of type "boolean" and `setCanToggle(true)`. `setCanToggle(true)` allows it to be toggled with one click without needing to have editing enabled for any other fields.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to paste the line concerning the SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX. Anyway thanks for the hint. I didn't know about setCanToggle, I thought that toggling was enabled by default.